# Chrome: Fill out same form many times for testing

Tags: forms, google-chrome, testing, browser

Is there some kind of tool (ideally for Chrome) in which I can fill out a long form that I am designing/testing many times?

I should be able to:

1. Fill out everything once and save it
2. Fill in the saved form with one button click
3. Fill out the form differently and save it as a different "profile"

I'm testing some things manually during development so I don't want a fully automated solution for this (I am using Symfony2.1 so I can write functional tests also). I just need a way to quickly fill out the form so I can save myself some time but I haven't been able to find a good Chrome extension or anything to do it. I remember Firebug in Firefox having something like this I think (I never used it though) so I imagine something exists.

The built in saved forms don't seem to be as useful for this task but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can check out iMacros for Chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp

Comment: Just trued this out, banging

Comment: @Flowpoke Did you find something worthy?

Answer (score 10):

Call it a rudimentary answer, but I believe the button shortcuts in Chrome accept Javascript. I've done this with FireFox by doing something like:

```
javascript:document.formname.fieldname.value='value';document.formname.fieldname2.value='value';document.formname.fieldname3.value='value';return false;
```

Comment: What is a button shortcuts in Chrome?

Comment: They're the Bookmarks Bar. The buttons that are under the address bar in Chrome.

Comment: These are also called bookmarklets or javascript bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

There are some plugins. I used the below one, and it can satisfy your requirement. 
This extension allows you to fill all form inputs with dummy data.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo

Here this one is for storing the form data and reusing it later. plugin populates with the data saved later when you want to fill it again.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-form-filler/hbgbedpagfcecmjmlfpndghfclhnmmll/details

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an extension, but I've always found the easiest way to test a form is with a little jQuery.

I put a link under the submit button:

```
<a href="#" id="fill_form">fillform</a>
```

Then I fill the form with jQuery.

```
$('#fill_form').click(function(event) {
    $("#name").val("Phoney Phoneyman");
    $("#phone").val("555 867-5309");
    $("#email").val("phoney@baloney.com");
    $("#password").val("123456");
    $("#password_conf").val("123456");
});
```

It takes about as long to do this as it does filling out the form initially and saves a ton of time.  A tiny bit more work and you could generate random values - or values from a list.

Just remember to delete it all when you're done.

Google's form filler is just always incorrect enough to create work rather than save time.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a chrome extension which exactly matches your needs, it may be worth a try - [SimpleFill](https://plugins.compzets.com/simplefill/).

It's really simple and is available for Chrome, Opera, and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Best form fill up  extension ever is [JunkFill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/junkfill/cajejbcjfkhgmfbapmhopccephhjedeb?hl=en).

I love it.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a Selenium extension for Chrome. Selenium is one of the most popular webdrivers, I've used this as well, and even though there are a few oddballs in there, it works well generally:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Another useful chrome extension [Formbot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formbot/ilnjaomgpkbmapjachcppgabkidbmnjc). When set to randomly fill the inputs, it will fill them with valid data.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the [Bug Magnet Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bug-magnet/efhedldbjahpgjcneebmbolkalbhckfi?hl=en).